# CakePHP "uses" variable in the controller seems to change model behavior?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When I use a controller's default model, and DO NOT set the $uses variable, the models behave as declared in their respective model files. However, when I use the $uses variable, don't seem to have any behaviors nor validation criteria attached.

Example:

```
     class OrdersController extends CakeCartAppController {
        public $helpers = array('CakeCart.ProductDisplay');
        public $components = array('CakeCart.AuthorizeNet','Security');
        public $uses = array('Order','CompanyLogin','Invoice');//COMMENTING THIS LINE OUT MAKES IT WORK!
```

...
...

```
     //see if order information validates
     $this->Order->set($orderinfo);
     if ($this->Order->validates()) {//ONLY WORKS WHEN THE USES VARIABLE IS NOT DECLARED
```

EDIT!

Solved it myself, sorry for the trouble. Basically, since this is a plugin, you must declare 'uses' associations within the namespace of the plugin:

```
    public $uses = array('CakeCart.Order','CompanyLogin','CakeCart.Invoice');
```

Comment: You should avoid using $uses at all. Generally you can get to models through relations and needing $uses indicates a possible problem in your code. There are legitimate cases for using various unrelated models in a controller such as a dashboard page, but then there are better ways to do it such as $this->loadModel()

Comment: Also add your edit as an answer and mark it as read so others see it's solved.

Comment: dogmatic, I agree. that's the better way to do it, however there are some edge cases where this makes more sense. Jeremy, added.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, sorry for the trouble. Basically, since this is a plugin, you must declare 'uses' associations within the namespace of the plugin:

```
public $uses = array('CakeCart.Order','CompanyLogin','CakeCart.Invoice');
```